# Setting variables in SQL functions/probs

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume I have a normal SQL procedure which has a few arguments.

During debugging it would be nice if i could assign some values to these arguments so that I can just highlight the body of the proc and execute it (as opposed to manually replace the variable with values.

Is there any way to do this? I tried:

```
@Date1 datetime,
@Date2 datetime

SET @Date1 = '2012-03-23'
```

but it doesn't like it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 
`DECLARE @Date1 datetime`
`SET @Date1 = '2012-03-23'`

Looks like you were missing the declare statement.  If it doesn't like the '2012-03-23' part, you may have to cast it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to do this, I suggest you consider adding a @Debug parameter to your procedures:

```
create procedure dbo.SomeProc @p1 int, @p2 int, @Debug bit = 0x0
as
set nocount on
begin

if @Debug = 0x1 -- set test values only if debugging
begin
print 'Start debugging'
set @p1 = 1
set @p2 = 2
end

/* your code continues here... */

end
```

Then when you want to test your code, just execute the procedure with `@Debug = 0x1` to execute the debugging code.

Comment: Maybe you wanna declare the `@Debug` parameter as an optional parameter

Comment: @Sung It is optional: it has a default value of 0x0

Answer (score 1):

Put 'declare' word in front of @Date1