# Error when executing query with variables in sp_send_dbmail

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to send emails individually to a list of recipients. I am receiving the error:

```
Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters
Msg 14661, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 478
Query execution failed: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Server xxxxxx, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "email@example.com" could not be bound.
```

Here is a simplified version of my code, asssuming table1 is a valid existing table and name and email are existing columns.

```
declare @current_mailaddress varchar(50), @query varchar(1000)
set @current_mailaddress = 'email@example.com'

set @query = 'select distinct name, email from table1 
              where email = ' + @current_email

exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
 @recipients = @current_email,
 @subject = 'test',
 @query = @query
```

So according to the error, the formatting (of presumably the @query) is wrong. I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the value of `@current_email` in quotes:

```
'SELECT ... WHERE email = ''' + @current_email + ''''
```

To see why, consider what your query currently looks like without it:

```
SELECT ... WHERE email = email@example.com
```

Any time you work with dynamic SQL, it's a good idea to PRINT the variable for debugging if you get a strange error; it's usually the case that the SQL string you've built is not the one you're expecting. I suggested an easy way to manage debugging code in another, unrelated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739306/setting-variables-in-sql-functions-probs/10739598#10739598).