# Invalid object name 'DQM.dbo.ST_0043_BLANK_CONSENT_SAP_SIEBEL'

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

**Hi all, Yes same person from an earlier question... I'm really bad when it comes to Cursors/SQL
I have been using the below stored procedure/cursor that I have made.. It compiles properly, the problem comes when i try to execute it I get this error:**

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'DQM.dbo.ST_0043_BLANK_CONSENT_SAP_SIEBEL'.

(0 row(s) affected)
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'DQM.dbo.ST_0044_CONSENT_SIEBEL_SAP_DIFF'.

(0 row(s) affected)
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'DQM.dbo.ST_0045_CONSENT_SIEBEL_BANNER_DIFF'.

**Now I know for a fact all of these objects exist as when I do a select all, i get rows returned. Any help would be appreciated.**

```
    USE [Adhoc_datafix]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CostTest_02]    Script Date: 01/10/2013 15:43:32 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CostTest_02]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Issue_id int;
DECLARE @Master_id int;
DECLARE @Issue_table varchar(255);
DECLARE @price real;
DECLARE @rowcount bigint;
DECLARE @sql varchar(3000)


DECLARE cost_cursor cursor FOR
SELECT [Issue Id], [Master Issue Id], [Issue Table], [Price]
from Adhoc_datafix..[IssueTable]
FOR UPDATE OF [Issue Id];

OPEN cost_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM cost_cursor into @Issue_ID, @Master_id, @Issue_table, @Price

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


SELECT @sql = 'Select count(*) from DQM.' + quotename(@Issue_table)
EXEC(@sql)
set @Rowcount = @@rowcount


UPDATE ADHOC_DATAFIX..[Issue Cost]
set [Issue Id] = @Issue_ID ,
    [Master Issue Id] = @Master_ID ,
    [Row Count] = @Rowcount,
    [Cost] = CAST(@Rowcount * @price as money)

--WHERE CURRENT OF cost_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM cost_cursor into @Issue_ID, @Master_id, @Issue_table, @Price
END

close cost_cursor;

DEALLOCATE cost_cursor;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are using `QUOTENAME()` to quote the schema and table name together:

```
select quotename('dbo.ST_0045_CONSENT_SIEBEL_BANNER_DIFF')
-- returns [dbo.ST_0045_CONSENT_SIEBEL_BANNER_DIFF]
```

So SQL Server thinks you are trying to query a table called `[dbo.ST_0045_CONSENT_SIEBEL_BANNER_DIFF]` in the `DQM` schema:

```
select * from DQM.[dbo.ST_0045_CONSENT_SIEBEL_BANNER_DIFF]
```

But you really want to query a table called `[ST_0045_CONSENT_SIEBEL_BANNER_DIFF]` in the `dbo` schema:

```
select * from DQM.dbo.[ST_0045_CONSENT_SIEBEL_BANNER_DIFF]
```

To fix this, either remove the `dbo.` prefix from the start of the `@Issue_Table` string and hard-code it after `DQM`, or if you want to support different schemas use `PARSENAME()` to get the schema and table name separately:

```
SELECT @sql = 'Select count(*) from DQM.' + quotename(parsename(@Issue_table, 2)) + N'.' + quotename(parsename(@Issue_table, 1))
```

And as a general suggestion, any time you work with dynamic SQL, [give yourself an easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739306/setting-variables-in-sql-functions-probs/10739598#10739598) to `PRINT`or `SELECT` the final string so you can see if the query you constructed is really correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was useful! And im not too worried about security as this is just an internal thing I will be using to draw up a report!